# Get list of links pinned to the taskbar

Tags: vbscript, taskbar

Is there anyway to retrieve a list or table or something of all of the applications/links you have pinned to the taskbar in VBScript?

I have a script that unpins certain ones by looking them up in the start menu essentially but I'm running this on different brands of computers out of the box (part of a setup script) but different brands of computers pin different applications to the taskbar by default.

I just want to get a list of whatever IS there and then call the unpin for that link

This is an example of the code I use to unpin an item

```
If objFSO.FileExists(strCurrentUserStartFolderPath & "\Programs\Internet Explorer.lnk") Then
    Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(strCurrentUserStartFolderPath & "\Programs")
    Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName("Internet Explorer.lnk")
    Set colVerbs = objFolderItem.Verbs
    For Each objVerb in colVerbs
        If Replace(objVerb.name, "&", "") = "Unpin from Taskbar" Then objVerb.DoIt
    Next
End If
```

Comment: As a general rule you aren't supposed to be messing around with the taskbar. Why are you doing this?

Comment: I have to configure a lot of computers for work and this is just part of my initial script to get them ready for clients, just clear all the junk the brand companies put on there.

Comment: So I take it you can't just setup one computer and use it as an image for the rest.

Comment: We were toying with that idea but haven't explored it fully yet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will print a list of items pinned to the TaskBar with of list of available verbs for each item.

```
const APPDATA = &H1a

Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application") 
Set oAppData = oShell.NameSpace(APPDATA)
sAppData = oAppData.Self.Path
set oTaskBar = oShell.NameSpace(sAppData & "\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar")

For Each oItem in oTaskBar.Items
  WScript.Echo oItem.Name
  For Each oVerb in oItem.Verbs
    WScript.Echo "    " & oVerb.Name
  Next
Next
```

Comment: It's possible to have items pinned to the taskbar that don't exist in this folder.

Comment: It appears this method no longer works. You can unpin items from the taskbar, but not pin them.